# Possible problems that may occur in CENTOS?

Tags: linux, centos, java, mysql, tomcat

I have developed an application on fedora 13 that works fine. The dependencies of this application are jre 1.6.0_26,tomcat webserver 6.0.18 and mysql 14.12 distrib 5.0.67.Now we need to extend the application to centos 5.5 both 32 and 64 bit. We have altered the coding.
Before launching it, I need your help. Kindly say your ideas and suggestion what may go wrong and what would create bug in centos 5.5 with the mentioned dependencies ???

Also guide me what can mismatch between 32 bit and 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just install [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), fire up a virtual machine and install [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30)? It's free and open source.

You may then test as you please, on more than one operating systems.